# has no exported member 'CoordinateReferenceSystem'

Tags: d3.js, angular-nvd3

Iam using suing `"d3": "^4.10.0",` and `"@types/d3": "^4.10.0",` in my angular 4 project , Suddenly its start throwing error

```
ERROR in @types/d3-geo/index.d.ts (39,19): Namespace '"@types/geojson/index"' has no exported member 'CoordinateReferenceSystem'.
```

I am come across this file which is using geojson 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-geo/index.d.ts

but I think type defination of geojson is not updated or , I am using worng version , can someone please help me.

Comment: 3 minutes ago I got the same problem. My ng build throws an error ".../node_modules/@types/geojson/index"' has no exported member 'CoordinateReferenceSystem'."

Comment: You can track the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/21794

Comment: `npm install @types/geojson@1.0.6 `  is worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a very similar error in an angular 4 app. It was fixed by installing `@types/geojson v 1.0.6`

I am not sure how we inherited the bug in the first place though - we have fixed version npm packages in our `package.json`. We have a suspicion `OpenLayers` might be using `d3`.

Comment: yes, you are right. later had identified the solution , see my comment